# Cannot retrieve card number/expiry date/CVC in vue. Stripe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I do understand that Stripe stores all of the information and I don't need to bother storing it on my side. However, I have a credit card design in the card details, which should be filled with information, once the user starts typing into the input area. How do I access the card number/expiry date/CVC on change? So that I can access it later and render it in my card UI. 
I need this only for card details page (while the user is typing, not for further situations)
The official documentation provides only value for postalCode:

```
value
string, object
An object similar to the one used for value when creating an Element.

Only present for non-sensitive values, like postalCode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the card details your customer is entering into a `card` Element. This is by design for PCI compliance reasons, so that your code never touches the customer's card details and so the card details are directly going to Stripe.

After tokenization, you can access other fields on the PaymentMethod object such as card's last4 digits, the card brand, etc, which you can display to customers.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the same information, just wanted to clarify.